# openTBS - create a new line in .odt document

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I use openTBS to generate letters in OpenOffice Writer (.odt documents). Address can have variable number of lines depending on existing/non-existing department name, person name etc. That's why I need to create new line inside place holder.

[h.address]

$TBS->MergeBlock('h', $header);

I have tried to use "\n" and "
" inside address. But none of them worked.

How can I set new line in placeholder in case of OpenOffice odt documents?

Thanks

Jan

Answer (score 3):

I have finally found a solution:

```
$address = 'Joe Doe'.'<text:line-break/>'.'xy street';
```

Placeholder must not be converted:

```
[h.address;strconv=no]
```

And it works :)